# How to read dc voltage using ESP-12E?

Tags: esp8266

I've a voltage source ranging from 0-100mV. I want to read the voltage using ESP-12E. I've connected voltage source to my A0 pin.
This is how my code looks like -

```
    const int AnalogIn  = A0;
    int readingIn = 0;
    void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop() {
    readingIn = analogRead(AnalogIn);
    Serial.println(readingIn);
    }
```

But my serial monitor is not giving the same reading as my Multimeter. Need help.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Since A0 is the ADC pin, what you are reading here is the output of ADC (which will be a value between 0 and 1023) on the ESP-12E and not the analog voltage value. It is the digital equivalent of your analog voltage signal. You will have to convert it into the corresponding analog voltage reading before printing on the serial monitor. The formula should be straightforward.

```
                        analog_value=(adc_value/1023)*5000mV
```

All the best!

Comment: Thank you so much. But I'm not getting accurate value. What could be the reason?

Comment: the ESP12's ADC ranges from 0 to 1v, not 0 to 5v...

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, dandavis. Basil, maybe you can replace 5000mV with 1000mV and see it if it works. If dandavis is right, you should be getting accurate results afterwards.